# Insert figure or table inside one paragraph instead between paragraphs

Tags: floats

When insert a table/fig, it is always floating somewhere between paragraphs. Is there a way to insert them inside of one paragraph, I dont mind to break the sentences.

Comment: Your claim that `table` and `figure` environments "always float somewhere between paragraphs" cannot be entirely correct. For instance, if a float is placed at top or bottom of a page, there is no reason to believe that paragraph break will either follow or precede the float, respectively. Please clarify your claim.

Comment: Thanks for replying. I mean, can I insert a table in the middle a long paragraph instead of at the end of the paragraph.

Comment: yes you can insert a figure mid-paragraph. If you get an error make a small complete document that shows the problem otherwise there isn't really any answer we can give here.

Comment: note that if the  tabular or image is part of the paragraph flow and must appear there, just use `tabular`  or `\includegraphics` directly. The _only_ reason to wrap them in `figure` or `table` environments is to mark them as floats that may be moved to help with page breaking.

Comment: Please also clarify what it is that you're trying to achieve by placing a `figure` or `table` environment -- which typically comes with a caption and often includes a legend -- in the middle of a (long?) paragraph. How are readers supposed to distinguish the float material from its surroundings? As @DavidCarlisle has noted, if you really need a table of graphic to show up in the middle of a paragraph, you probably shouldn't be using `table` and `figure` environments to begin with. Instead, you should be using a `tabular` environment or an `\includegraphics` statement *inside* the paragraph.

Comment: I think what you want could be achieved with the `wrapfig` package, which provides `wrapfigure` and `wraptable` environments that allow figures and table to be wrapped in text. See [ctan.org/pkg/wrapfig](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/wrapfig).